# Url pattern regex in django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

This is a a basic question but I'm having trouble finding the answer in in docs:

Lets say I have a url like:

```
http://example.com/part1/part2
```

and I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'xxx', name='yyy'),

)
```

What part of the url string above is attempted to be matched by the regex between `^` and `$`?

I've read through numerous sources and docs including:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#module-django.core.urlresolvers
- http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against) clearly:

> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python
>   string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain
>   name.
>
> For example, in a request to http://www.example.com/myapp/, the
>   URLconf will look for myapp/.
>
> In a request to http://www.example.com/myapp/?page=3, the URLconf will
>   look for myapp/.
>
> The URLconf doesn’t look at the request method. In other words, all
>   request methods – POST, GET, HEAD, etc. – will be routed to the same
>   function for the same URL.

In your case, `part1/part2` string would be searched against.

Comment: Thank you Alecxe for pointing out the location of that explanation in the docs. I have a follow up question. At the explanation it states: "The URLconf searches against the requested URL," does the URL refer to just "part1/part2" I thought a URL refers to "http://example.com/part1/part2"

Comment: @user61629 you are welcome. domain name is not included in the check, see `This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain name`.

Comment: Thank you, So for my understanding , if django defines the URL as "part1/part2" , what does it call "example.com/part1/part2" ?

Comment: @user61629 well, they URL is definitely the whole string `http://example.com/part1/part2`, `part1/part2` can be referred as "path", but it is just a part of a URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find it a bit confusing though, especially for beginners.

Comment: @user61629 it is okay, it is a good, legitimate and, most importantly, it is very specific and clear question - that's why I've upvoted it. Thanks.

Comment: @user61629: Including the domain would be inconvenient if you use the same code with different domains.